# Java NoClassDefFoundError amf

Tags: java, deserialization, blazeds, amf

I'm trying to compile a java snippet into a jar file, I got into a classical java runtime exception but I'm unable to solve the problem.
This is the code, borrowed from Markus Wulftange:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import flex.messaging.io.SerializationContext;
import flex.messaging.io.amf.ActionContext;
import flex.messaging.io.amf.ActionMessage;
import flex.messaging.io.amf.AmfMessageDeserializer;
import flex.messaging.io.amf.AmfMessageSerializer;
import flex.messaging.io.amf.MessageBody;

public class Amf3ExternalizableUnicastRef {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    if (args.length < 2 || (args.length == 3 && !args[0].equals("-d"))) {
        System.err.println("usage: java -jar " + Amf3ExternalizableUnicastRef.class.getSimpleName() + ".jar [-d] <host> <port>");
        return;
    }
    boolean doDeserialize = false;
    if (args.length == 3) {
        doDeserialize = true;
        args = Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, args.length);
    }

    // generate the UnicastRef object
    Object unicastRef = generateUnicastRef(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));

    // serialize object to AMF message
    byte[] amf = serialize(unicastRef);

    // deserialize AMF message
    if (doDeserialize) {
        deserialize(amf);
    } else {
        System.out.write(amf);
    }
}

public static Object generateUnicastRef(String host, int port) {
    java.rmi.server.ObjID objId = new java.rmi.server.ObjID();
    sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint endpoint = new sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint(host, port);
    sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef liveRef = new sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef(objId, endpoint, false);
    return new sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef(liveRef);
}

public static byte[] serialize(Object data) throws IOException {
    MessageBody body = new MessageBody();
    body.setData(data);

    ActionMessage message = new ActionMessage();
    message.addBody(body);

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    AmfMessageSerializer serializer = new AmfMessageSerializer();
    serializer.initialize(SerializationContext.getSerializationContext(), out, null);
    serializer.writeMessage(message);

    return out.toByteArray();
}

public static void deserialize(byte[] amf) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(amf);

    AmfMessageDeserializer deserializer = new AmfMessageDeserializer();
    deserializer.initialize(SerializationContext.getSerializationContext(), in, null);
    deserializer.readMessage(new ActionMessage(), new ActionContext());
  }
}
```

Using the package flex-messaging-core, located in the same directory, I compiled into a jar with 
`javac -cp flex...jar sourcefile.java.`

Then compiled to a jar with 
`jar -cfm myjar.jar MANIFEST.ML myclass.class`.

But then, when running from shell with proper arguments 
`java -jar myjar.jar -d 127.0.0.1 8000`
it throws an Exception in threadmain `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : flex/messaging/io/amf/MessageBody`.

I googled and tried all solutions for 2 days, but really can't solve the problem by myself, can I kindly ask for a little help?

Comment: NoClassDef means the compiler didn't find that class. You might verify if the package has this class, if the paths are all correct, if you linked the dependencies...

Comment: Hi Leonardo, thanks for your answer, I already checked for the package, and it has the "offensor" class, which is flex.messaging.io.amf.MessageBody. Also the classpath and dependecies appear to be correct

Comment: What is your Manifest.ml? Probably you should use the same classpath for executing the jar as you used to compile the class: java -cp flex...jar -jar myjar.jar -d 127.0.0.1 8000

Comment: My manifest.ml contains these headers          Manifest-Version: 1.0    Main-Class: Amf3ExternalizableUnicastRef   Class-Path: flex-messaging-core-4.7.2.jar

Comment: Just to be clear, the jar compiles and executes until it calls Messagebody class,  I placed some System.out.println to pinpoint that

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be MANIFEST.MF, not MANIFEST.ML?